# How does Signal's Double Ratchet algorithm handle multiple clients?

Tags: encryption

I've got only very basic knowledge concerning security and encryption techniques and like to know how multiple recipient applications are handled in the Signal messenger (in very short terms, without having to read the specification). Very naively and in simplified terms I'd say the sender of a message holds a public key of its recipient, which he uses to encrypt a symmetric key, which in turn is used to encrypt the actual message payload. But how does this work if the recipient has, for instance, a mobile- and a desktop app. Both need to receive the message, but they most likely have different key pairs (unless the private key is exchanged among them in some way, which is - in my understanding - not a good idea). A naive solution could be the sender encrypting and sending the message twice, with two different keys.

Answer (score 0):

In solutions like this when implementing multiple device encryption, private keys are either migrated to all devices (a shared private key) or all of the public keys are published to a directory for discovery. For the discovery to be trustworthy it needs to be built on a tamper-evident log structure, for example, one like Google's Key Transparency.